# Save video from UIImagePickerController in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I use until now this code for saving video that i get from `UIImagePickerController`:

```
        NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        path = [kFilesSaveDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@/Vid%d.mov",album.albumName,album.lastfile];
        path2 = [kFilesSaveDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@/VidImg%d.png",album.albumName,album.lastfile];

        [videoData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];

        [[videoPlayer moviePlayer] setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
        UIImage *image = [[videoPlayer moviePlayer] thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption: MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
        [[videoPlayer moviePlayer] setContentURL:nil];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path2 atomically:YES];
```

Until now in ios 4 it work without any problems, but when i try to use it now in ios 5 ,it do two problems:

1. it give me nil for the img.

2.it not show me the video when i want to show it with this code :

```
[[videoPlayer moviePlayer] setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:choosen.bigpath]];

[self presentModalViewController:videoPlayer animated:YES];

[[videoPlayer moviePlayer] play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me -

```
NSURL *mediaUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaUrl];
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
        thumbnail = [[moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame] retain];
        [moviePlayer release];
        [layer release];
```

I added this code to this delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Hope it works for you also :)